# C# StreamWriter not writing correctly

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, streamwriter

I am pulling data from a sproc and writing each column to a file. One of the columns I am pulling from is a memo field allowing up to 4096 characters and hard carriage returns. I have updated my query to remove tabs and returns, which seems to work. When I export my query results to a file the memo column is all on one line. However, when I write the data to a file using stream writer it splits the data up over multiple lines. Any help here is greatly appreciated.

C# Code:

```
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp\\Test.txt");
    DataSet ds = GetData(); //call sproc, return data
    foreach(DataRow dr in ds) {
       sw.WriteLine(dr["Column1"] + "|" + dr["MemoColumn"] + "|" + dr["Column3"]);
    }
```

Sql Query:

```
    SELECT replace(replace(replace(isnull(MEMOCOLUMN, ''), CHAR(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(9), '')
    FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: Did you also remove `\n`s?

Comment: Yes I tried doing: dr["MemoColumn"].ToString().Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\t", " ");      Still didn't work

Comment: @SLaks `\r` and `\n` are CHAR(13) and CHAR(10) possibly not in that order.

Comment: Tried just using sw.Write and placing a "\n" at the end as well. Didn't work.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Not in that order.

Comment: @btjordan23: That line doesn't actually do anything.  Strings are immutable.

Comment: Place the output in a TextBox.  Place text in char array and write out each Int value to see what is getting thru.

Comment: @SLaks how should I remove the "\n"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work, there might be typos, but the process should be functional.

```
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Temp\\Test.txt")) 
    {
     DataSet ds = GetData(); //call sproc, return data
     foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Rows) 
     {
       var column = string.IsNullOrEmpty((dr["MemoColumn"].ToString()) ? string.Empty : 
                    dr["MemoColumn"].ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);

       sw.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2}", dr["Column1"], column, dr["Column3"]);
     }
    }
```

Comment: `ToString()` will never return null.

Comment: True, that check could be removed.